# simple QueryOver : Unrecognised method call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a simple QueryOver

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>().Where(p => p.Number.Equals(number));
```

Number field type is int.
This query has a runtime error by this message:

> Unrecognised method call: System.Int32:Boolean Equals(Int32)

Comment: can you post the mapping of `Person`? also you can try `.Where(p => p.Number == number`

Comment: Thanks! The Problem resolved by replacement '==' leiu equals. What is different between '==' and 'Equals' in field by int Type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `==` operator generates a [BinaryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx) which can be converted to SQL and the `.Equals()` method generates a [MethodCallExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx) which apparently is *not* converted to SQL.

Usually the binary operators are handled in `QueryOver` and also in Linq but only a few method calls are handled (`string.Contains`, `array.Contains`, etc.) so you better use operators when possible.

Also remember that the operators/method calls are not actually executed, but converted SQL statements so if you have custom overrides/implementations for them they might not work as expected.

Given the above your code would be rewritten as:

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>().Where(p => p.Number == number);
```